# QGIS connect SQL Server database locally throws error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied"

Tags: sql-server, qgis

I am trying to connect QGIS with a local SQL Server database, but its not working, I get this error:

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

I tried to change the Host for many values such as (localhost, 127.0.0.1, instance name which is `MSSQLSERVER`.

Also I enabled TCP/IP, Named Pipes then restarted the service, with no luck, can anyone help?

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` is the name of the default, unnamed instance - to connect to it, use `.` or `(local)` as server/instance name - do **not** specify `MSSQLSERVER` as the instance name!

Comment: What's the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shots? A complete error message usually gives you enough clues to indicate whether it's problems locating the service (through SQL Browser service), connecting to it, or authenticating against it.

Comment: @marc_s when I tried to set . as Host value I got another error related to user, Error opening connection: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed QODBC3: Unable to connect

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the previous full error was, Error opening connection: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed QODBC3: Unable to connect

Comment: @marc_s to solve this error (Login failed for user 'sa') , I went to  server - > Properties -> Security -> set server Authentication to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", but this option is already selected, and the error still.. is there any thing I need to check?

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92529/mssql-connection-settings-for-qgis-on-windows help?

Comment: @IanTurton unfortunately dose not help, even I downloaded (AccessDatabaseEngine driver)  with no luck ..

Comment: here is the reason why user failed as shown in sql error log; Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only.

Comment: Did you only recently change the authentication type of the instance from "Windows Authentication mode" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"? You need to restart the instance for such changes to take effect.